# With gradle, how do I express a compile time ONLY dependency from a local jar?

Tags: gradle

I have a project structured like this:

```
MainProject

|
|---- ExampleModule
|         \-src
|         \-libs
|                \-LibraryModule-0.1.jar
|
|---- LibraryModule (from existing source)
```

I have a buildscript that executes these tasks:

1. build/compile LibraryModule
2. make a jar with destinationDir set to ExampleModule/libs/
3. assemble ExampleModule, which depends on LibraryModule-0.1.jar
4. run

This seems simple, except I need to use compileOnly/provided with this local jar, as it is not a runtime dependency. How would I write that in my ExampleModule build.gradle file?

This is what I currently have:

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly 'libs:LibraryModule-0.1.jar'
}
```

Comment: https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies You're absolutely wrong there. How do you think annotation processors work?

Comment: @PrestonGarno don't get excited from people's incorrect comments. When you remain calm, and answer to the point like you did here - people will recognize you as professional. If I were you I'd remove my last comment and publish the answer!

Comment: @alfasin good point, although I think it's good to call out low effort comments like that, enough developers that I know personally aren't active here for that very reason.

Comment: @GabeSechan forgot to tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618416/with-gradle-how-do-i-express-a-compile-time-only-dependency-from-a-local-jar/42619105#comment72365619_42618416

Comment: @GhostCat same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618416/with-gradle-how-do-i-express-a-compile-time-only-dependency-from-a-local-jar/42619105#comment72398253_42618416

Comment: @PrestonGarno Annotation processors are a separate build step.  Calling them a dependency is an abuse of the term.

Comment: @GabeSechan please specify which build process you're talking about - gradle or javac.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but my question is clearly about the gradle build process and there is no 'build step' for annotation processors in gradle (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/java-annotation-processing.md).  If the processor is listed as being on the classpath then javac (i.e. the compileJava build step in gradle) will include it in compilation.

Comment: Interestingly enough I thought to myself about that rare case of annotation processing when I wrote my comment. But as that is so rare I pushed my own doubts away. I am glad that you didn't get too discouraged and found some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local jars, just like any dependency from mavenCentral or jcenter, if you have a version number at the end of the jar file name it has to be expressed like so:

```
compileOnly 'libs:LibraryModule-build:0.1'
```

Note that if I had named my jar 'LibraryModule.jar', simply putting

```
compileOnly 'libs:LibraryModule'
```

would have worked.

Note - if you are using gradle in your project for developing annotation processing tools or anything else that depends only at compile time it's recommended that you use [gradle-apt-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin/). Also, [here is an informative page in the gradle official repo about current support for annotation processors.](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/java-annotation-processing.md)

Comment: Thanks for publishing an answer, if you can also add links to online resources that are relevant it would be superb!

Comment: @alfasin I didn't find anything online about it, interestingly enough.  Probably because the only use case (that I can think of) for a compile time only dependency with a local jar would be for developing meta-programming libraries and that's not something that's very well documented when it comes to java & gradle (annotation processing was included JDK 1.6+ I believe, and gradle does not officially support this yet).  I figured it out after I decided to cut the jar name down to only simple chars to account for regexes and whatever goes on behind the scenes with gradle for parsing.